# Incorrect Time Calculation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winterbash

I think there may be a problem with the time on the StackExchange servers. I checked my profile today and noticed that I had received the "And I Feel Fine" hat, which states that it is for having posted or voted on December 21st, yet it is the 20th of December.

Given that I am on the east, and StackExchange is also based on the east coast, one would reasonably expect that the server's time would be set to the east coast's time zone.[image]

[image]

Is the server time set to something like Australia's timezone, or perhaps a bug in the code that determines what hats a user has earned?

Comment: this is discussed in depth at MSO: **[Off by twelve error? — “And I Feel Fine” hat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159577/165773)**

Answer (score 6):

There is a +/- 12 hour leeway on the hats. Stack Exchange time is based on UTC. This is expected behavior. [Here is a comment by Nick Craver about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159577/off-by-twelve-error-and-i-feel-fine-hat#comment462135_159579), as part of a larger Meta Stack Overflow discussion.